# Eclipse file doesn't appear in commit

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I have a large Eclipse project with a git repository and with multiple files, and today a class stopped behaving properly: when edited the > sign doesn't appear in front of the file's name, and the file's icon has this blue tick I never saw before. I also tried deleting the file and recreating it (and then pasting all the code it had), but to  no avail.

Here's what the file looks like:
[image: The screenshot of the problem.]

Did I accidentally press a hotkey that did this? I also recently started using Eclipse's task system, so maybe it is linked?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you somehow marked it as `assume-valid`. Check [the documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) and try [this fix](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Menu_Actions) to mark it as `No Assume unchanged`:

> This setting can be switched on with the menu action Team > Assume unchanged and switched back with the menu action Team > No Assume unchanged.